# How do I preserve a /home directory when doing a fresh Linux installation?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm running a Linux Mint 19.3 XFCE system on one of my laptops. I intend to switch to Kubuntu Fossa once it becomes stable. The /home folder is on a seperate partition and I will exclude it from being formatted during the new installation. I'll of course make a backup of the /home directory anyway.

From what I understand the UID will most likely change after a new installation, even when the same username is used - correct me if I'm wrong.
So, I was wondering if I can simply recursively `chown` the /home/$USER folder to the new user/UID afterwards?
Or is it better to untar the home backup after the installation with the new user?
And are there any other potential problems with the contents of my /home partition I should be aware of?

Comment: Whenever before any action on partition do a backup ; then Just note where it is physically & be carefully about it. Note its device name (for example /dev/sda3) to ensure there is no UUID new initialization.  Just ignore it for all of the installation process (don't use it at all).  after installation change /etc/fstab & create or change ID/GUID of all your users who have theirs home ; then you mount it on the currently empty "/home" then `mount -a`  ; that's all you need.

Comment: I'm not worried about the device UUIDs in fstbab, I was able to fix that in the past when doing upgrades. My main concern is the UID stored in the ext4 filesystem of the home folder: it's 1000 at the moment and I don't have any other users under /home. Or will this simply be recognized as identical when I choose the same username during a fresh installation?

Comment: that's why I mean IGNORE  the UID and concentrate on real device naming convention to avoid any risks, so you can ignore the UID issues whatever this means for the chosen distrib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost certainly don't need to do anything at all. The default UID for the default user on most (all?) modern distributions is `1000`. I have kept essentially the same `/home` directory for years across multiple different distributions. While that can sometimes cause issues with older settings files, if that happens, it's trivial to fix by deleting the offending file.

So, as long as you have `/home` in a separate partition, it will most likely work out of the box. If, for some weird reason, you do change the UID then yes, running `chown` to change the file ownership will work perfectly well.

Comment: Wouldn't that be `chown`?

Comment: @RudiC d'oh! Of course it would! Fixed now, thanks.